# app engine python gcloud not updating instance

Tags: python, google-app-engine, versioning, gcloud

[image][image]I keep running this command:

> gcloud app deploy service_backend.yaml --stop-previous-version
>   --version test-0-5-8

over and over again (increasing the final version digit each time)
and each time and go look at the log output from my code
it show's me logging from an PRIOR/earlier version of the code
but listed under the "test-0-5-8" version

either I'm losing my mind or something very strange is going on
I've tried this 30 times over 3 days before posting this embarrassing issue because I assume I must be causing this somehow but I'm at a total loss as to how

Comment: Maybe try adding `--promote` option as well? Otherwise please show more info, like deployment log, maybe the app's versions/instance screens in the console?

Comment: thanks Dan.....I'm still seeing the same weirdness.....I'll attach the deploy log & the screenshots above.  Your insights are most appreciated.

Comment: ok....I'm pulling my hair out here....there MUST be some situation under which gCloud fails or the instance stays stuck with old code.....

Google.....I really need someone to look at my config to figure out why logged errors with the BRAND NEW version ID are showing code and line #'s of OLD versions of our code....

Comment: When this originally happened, Google acknowledged it was a bug on their end.  Now it seems to be happening again and I'm pulling my hair out over it....is anyone else seeing Python code not get updated in a timely fashion?

Comment: What do you see on the versions page? The screen you shown indicates that version `test-0-6-0` is configured to carry all traffic, not  `test-0-5-8`. Try switching traffic to the version you desire.

Comment: sorry Dan....that screenshot is from many months ago so please ignore it.   This problem has just resurfaced.   GAE show's to be running the version I just deployed but the Logs clearly indicated that it's running an old version because I've modified my logging stmts in an effort to see which version is running.

Comment: Hi Dewey, is it possible for you to update the screenshots? I also don't see the referenced logs. Thanks

Comment: I could certainly update that image but it won't help.  In fact, the request makes me suspect I have miscommunicated the problem.  Google's consoles (versions, instances, logging, etc) DO SHOW the newly deployed version.  But when I go read my OWN logging statements, it makes it clear that the OLD CODE is still running DESPITE what the GCloud dashboards show me.   I know it sounds crazy but it happened once before & Google admitted it was their fault on my last support ticket.

Comment: To be really certain, I went into several functions and added lines like: logging.info("1) ...") and  ("2)....")  and I'm not seeing those show up....only the old logs without the "#)" prefix.... as such, I don't think that showing you log output would help solve the problem either but I can certainly do that.

Comment: As it may potentially be a defect on the Google platform and most likely lead to a specific situation which may require some exchange of project information to reproduce the behavior you described, can you please submit a [defect report](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues) as described in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that we can look on your project further? 

Feel free to update this thread as soon as a resolution is reached.

Comment: Hey Kenworth....thanks for your response.
I have filed this report
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72348659
but I'm really not getting anywhere with them.
Its frustrating at the least

Comment: are you updating the version in the service_backend.yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem before, and I think I solved it by deleting the .pyc files in my repo before deploying.
Could you try that?

Comment: Where is repo? Is it in Google Cloud?

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot share this repository as it is private and does not belong to me.